# Tool strip Menu Item has no invoke method, how to update with background thread

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

IntelliSense states that Tool strip Menu Item has no invoke method. I get red squiggly lines. How do I update without delegate / invoke?

```
      Private Delegate Sub AppendTSMIDelegate(ByVal TMSI As ToolStripMenuItem, ByVal b As Boolean)
Private Sub AppendTSMI(ByVal TSMI As ToolStripMenuItem, ByVal b As Boolean)
    If **TSMI.InvokeRequired** Then
        TSMI.Invoke(New AppendTSMIDelegate(AddressOf AppendTSMI), New Object() {TSMI, b})
    Else
        'TSMI.
    End If
```

Comment: Use the form's members.  It doesn't matter which object you use those members of, as long as it is owned by the appropriate thread.  By the way, there's no need to declare your own delegate type when you can use `Action` for subs and `Func` for functions.

Comment: Thanks, I will read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to check the invoke status on the toolstrip instead. Much thought and reading finally gave me the answer!

```
Private Sub AppendTSMI(ByVal TSMI As ToolStripMenuItem, ByVal b As Boolean)

    Dim ST1 As StatusStrip = StatusStrip1

    If ST1.InvokeRequired Then
        ST1.Invoke(New AppendTSMIDelegate(AddressOf AppendTSMI), New Object() {TSMI, b})
    Else
        TSMI.Checked = b
    End If

End Sub
```